# Seems SQL Server can't search by result of function. Any way around this?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, optimization

I created two tables, let's call them `foo` and `bar`. Both tables contain a number. `foo` has an index on this column. `foo` contains a large number of rows while `bar` has only a handful. I then write

```
select * 
from foo 
where number in (select number from bar)
```

As I'd expect, this query executes very fast. It finds the 3 records I had in bar, and even though foo has 80,000+ records, it does an indexed look up on these three values and returns the result in a fraction of a second.

Then I wrote a function "echo" that does nothing except take an integer as a parameter and return that integer, i.e. the entire text of echo is "return @x".

Then I try this query:

```
select * 
from foo 
where number in (select dbo.echo(number) from bar)
```

With the exact same data, this query is much slower. When I examine the query plans, it turns out that the first query uses the index to quickly find the selected records, but the second query does not, and instead does a sequential search of the entire table.

Note that this is not the same as a query where we render an index useless. Like if I'd said, "where dbo.echo(number)=42", then sure, the index on number is now useless (presumably the DB engine doesn't know that the function just returns its input, as such a function would be useless in real life, I'm not surprised they don't build in special handling for it), so the DB engine has no choice but to sequentially search the entire table. But here, it executes the function on a field from bar. It should then be able to look that value up in the index on foo just as well as if I had given a value not wrapped in a function.

Why? And more important, is there some way around this? Of course the real problem that led to this experiment was a function that does more than just return its parameter, it's actually doing some decryption. But my experiment here proves that just using a function cripples the query plan.

Here's my actual tables for my experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[foo]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [number] [int] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)

CREATE INDEX [ix_foo_number] ON [dbo].[foo] ([number] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bar]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [number] [int] NULL,
    [some_value] [varchar](10) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)

create function [dbo].[echo](@x int) returns int
as
begin
    return @x
end
```

Then I populated foo with 82,000 records and bar with 3 records.

And the queries are:

```
select * from foo where number in (select number from bar)

select * from foo where number in (select dbo.echo(number) from bar)
```

Plan cost for the first query is 0.025, for the second is 0.848. Over 30 times the cost because I added a do-nothing function. Okay, still small, but in the real query that prompted this, the cost skyrocketed to over 500 and resulted in time outs.

Comment: Functions, by default, are not "deterministic" (i.e. SQL Server cannot know that it will always get the exact same result for the exact same input), and so it short-circuits a ton of potential optimizations. Further, it doesn't magically know what the function does, so it has to call the function for every row, which means it can't directly seek to an index as easily (or even at all). Functions are almost (but not quite) always performance killers, and should be used in moderation, only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @pmbAustin That is false. UDFs are a great tool for improving performance in queries because they're composable - so the query execution engine can recompose them as necessary - both scalar UDFs and Table-valued UDFs. Scalar UDFs can be used inappropriately, of course, such as using a Correlated Subquery(in OP's exmaple) - consider using `CROSS APPLY` instead.

Comment: Yeah, not false @Dai. Please note My "not always" disclaimer. And refer to the article I linked in the answer below.

Comment: @pmbAustin Certainly true that I would not expect the optimizer to realize that my function just returns the input value and optimize just like it would if I just handed it the value directly. But I'd expect it would read the 3 records, perform the function for each, and then have 3 values that it could use to do index lookups. At that point it should be no different than if I had given it 3 constants. Or so I would have thought, but no.

Comment: The optimizer basically doesn't assume anything. So even though there are three values, it doesn't know that. It's going to call the function for every record it needs to in order to compare it, so 82,000 times in your case. It doesn't "know" that the result is deterministic. It doesn't "know" that the result won't change with every execution (like, say, GETDATE() does).

Comment: @pmbAustin Ooh, now that's an interesting point. I was thinking that "non-deterministic" means that if a function operates on a field from record A, that every time it reads record A it must execute the function again. But you're taking it a step farther. If it's comparing the results of a function on a field in record A to a field in record B, then every time it compares to a new B it has to execute the function again. That reasoning does explain the observed behavior. So ... is there any way to tell the optimizer that a function is deterministic?

Comment: You can try defining the function "WITH SCHEMABINDING" and see if that has any effect... I understand it does in some cases, but it's not really helped me out yet. I don't entirely understand the nuances here, because I've seen places where using a function is MUCH faster, but in most cases, it's a LOT slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can refer you to this excellent blog post that discusses the performance issues of scalar functions in SQL Server:

[T-SQL User-Defined Functions: the good, the bad, and the ugly (part 1)](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly)

Note that there are additional parts that go into even more detail.

Added from the comments above:

The optimizer basically doesn't assume anything. So even though there are three values, it doesn't know that. It's going to call the function for every record it needs to in order to compare it, so 82,000 times in your case. It doesn't "know" that the result is deterministic. It doesn't "know" that the result won't change with every execution (like, say, GETDATE() does). Therefore it does not and can't "cache" it.

You can try defining the function "WITH SCHEMABINDING" and see if that has any effect... I understand it does in some cases, but it's not really helped me out yet. I don't entirely understand the nuances here, because I've seen places where using a function is MUCH faster, but in most cases, it's a LOT slower.

Comment: I read the linked page. Interesting, but doesn't directly answer my question. Even granting that the DB engine horribly underestimates the cost of executing a function, in my example it only has to do it 3 times. It can't be THAT expensive. The statement in there about, the optimizer won't use parallelism when there's a function involved is not directly relevant but is similar. For some reason the optimizer won't do an indexed search on the result of a function, apparently.

Comment: Your last comment was actually the most useful information I got here rather than your answer, but as I can't mark a comment as the selected answer, I'll mark this answer. :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer with the comment, just to make it clear for any future readers.

Comment: In practice, I've totally reworked the query and now I get decent performance. But I still want to investigate this issue further, as it's likely to come up again in another context.

Answer (score 0):

In first select you use clear value for condition, but in second query, server must execute 3times a function and after that,use result of function for condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because your doing things backwards. When you search on the decrypted value, the engine has no choice but to decrypt the value from EVERY row in the table in order to do the comparison. Refer to [Indexing an encrypted column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344011/indexing-an-encrypted-column-in-sql-server) for a similar discussion about indexing - which is likely the next thing you will need to address. And if you search on the words "search encrypted column" you will lots of additional discussions - some very important ones if encryption is a major concern.

Comment: Hmm, but why would it have to decrypt every record in this example? I'm taking all the records from bar -- in this example only 3 -- and "decrypting" the values in those 3 records. Then I'm doing a look-up on foo where the data is not encrypted, so it should be able to do a straight look-up. Maybe the problem is moot because I should be encrypting the data in foo also, but I find the behavior of the engine here puzzling.

Comment: Ignore your example. You have over-simplified it. If the column you are searching is encrypted, you can only search it in one of two ways (which is over-simplified but sufficient for this). You decrypt the column and compare it to the actual value of interest - which is the impression I get from your discussion. If that is your approach, the engine must decrypt the column in every row in order to compare it to a particular value. The problem is that this approach is slow - and indexing the encrypted value provides no benefit in this case.

Comment: The other approach (alluded to in link) is to search on the encrypted value (really, a sort of surrogate). Without going into too much detail, you generate and store a hash which is used for searching (because the typical encryption methods do not generate the same encrypted value for the same raw value at different times). A broader discussion is here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2005/12/22/sql-server-2005-searching-encrypted-data/

Comment: And one more comment. Scalar functions tend to kill performance - as the others have already mentioned.

Comment: Well yes, IF the value in foo was encrypted, then to search on it would require decrypting it, which would require a sequential search. And then you say "ignore your example". You're ignoring my question and answering a question I didn't ask! :-) Everything you say here is true ... but not relevant to my question.

Comment: You can read about the performance implications here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx. In questions like this, you always look at the plan. And the UDF plan is much worse because the function is treated as a black box. My plans -> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyCWAc7g-